# Airport in Japan without Retina Scan

Tags: customs-and-immigration, airports, japan

I will be flying at the start of 2018 to Japan and I'm, for various privacy reasons, not comfortable with officials taking a retina scan. Fingerprints ought to be enough!

Therefore: Which airports in Japan do not take retina scans? (I know that all of them take fingerprints of all 10 fingers.)

I'd be especially interested in personal experiences going through the airports in Tokyo and/or Osaka.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67281/discussion-on-question-by-woza-airport-in-japan-without-retina-scan).

Comment: I travelled to Japan earlier this year. I don't recall any such data being exctracted from me!

Comment: This got lost in the chat, but I think it's worth adding to the question--retina scan vs iris scan--very different, one is much faster with a much simpler camera, there are commercial iris scan cameras that could be mistaken for nice pocket cameras and the process could be mistaken for a normal photo.

Comment: I also mentioned this in a comment below, and agree with @user3067860 - pretty much all security devices that scan your eyes are *iris* scanners, the phrase 'retina scanner' is usually used by laypeople to describe iris scanners. A retina scan is usually only done at an opticians, for health reasons. This is because in general the iris doesn't change and can therefore be used as a biometric identifier, whereas the retina changes appearance with age and health.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, and this is from personal experience since I visit Japan several times a year, these are **no** airports in Japan that do retina scans.  You will be fingerprinted (index fingers only, not 10 digits) and photographed, but the camera used for the latter is akin to a consumer webcam ([see photo here](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-japan-fingerprinting/japan-fingerprints-foreigners-as-anti-terror-move-idUST23858020071120)) and not sufficient to extract retinal information.  Retinal scans also require aligning your eyes with the scanner at close range, which is not done at Japanese airports.

Also, the facial recognition gates are currently for Japanese citizens only, compare your face against the biometric image in your passport, and do indeed work with a single shot (although they may allow a second attempt if they can't match the first time around).

Comment: That's very reassuring to know. Is your experience based on flying to any of the airport Haneda, Narita in Tokyo (or Kansai in Osaka) ? (I wanted to upvote, but I see I need at least 15 reputation points to do that :(

Comment: @woza I can confirm that there were no retinal scans in Narita when I traveled through there recently.

Comment: Since when is the print and photograph? I didn't get that a couple years ago.

Comment: @woza I fly into both Haneda and Narita regularly.  Don't think I've been back to Kansai since they instituted the fingerprint scans.

Comment: @Kevin Since 2007: https://www.reuters.com/article/us-japan-fingerprinting/japan-fingerprints-foreigners-as-anti-terror-move-idUST23858020071120

Comment: huh, I have absolutely no memory of that. Maybe I'm just used to it because I'm global entry?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thanks a lot for confirming. The pictures were in your case taking with a commercial webcam as well?

Comment: The machine makes the sound of a japanese girl as it instructs you on how your photo will be taken (which is why I even remember it), it looked like a commercial webcam - I can't be sure but it definitely _wasn't_ a retinal scanner.

Comment: @jpatokal Having arrived in Kansai only weeks ago, I can confirm that your description is accurate there too. In Kansai, they actually take your photo/index finger prints twice for some reason: once at very small semi-automated stands occupied by a helper who can serve two at once and once with the actual immigration officers. Since I never entered through Haneda or Narita, I don’t know if they do that there, too.

Comment: @Jan I also entered Kansai recently, and I don't remember getting fingerprinted twice.  Maybe it depends what line you're in or how busy it is.

Comment: This sounds accurate. I've visited Japan from America 3 times in the past 3 years, always through Narita. I can't remember whether they just did my index fingers or all 10, but I clearly remember the webcam-looking camera they took my photograph with. I did have to remove my glasses for the photo, but there was no way they were scanning my retinas with that thing.

Comment: @Kimball When you go into the immigration hall first you go straight ahead to the opposite side to the small stall thingys, that’s where I recall the first fingerprint. Then you line up and are dispatched to the actual officers (on the right when viewed from the side you enter from) who I recall you getting fingerprinted again. Both occasions also include a photo.

Comment: @Jan It's possible I just completely forgot this (my recent airport trips have somewhat blended together at this point, and I was pretty tired when I arrived), but I honestly have no recollection of going to a small stall first (and it was only a month ago).

Comment: Today's news:  https://japantoday.com/category/national/facial-recognition-gates-for-japanese-launched-at-haneda-airport

Answer (score 19):

The chaos that would ensue if *any* airport tried to retina scan everyone would be absolutely incredible. See, I had a retina scan made or attempted to when I applied for my NEXUS card. It is *not* fast and in my case for example, it failed and so they attempted it multiple times before just giving up. It is telling that the NEXUS centre at YVR schedules these scans (just the scans, not interviews) at *30 minute* intervals!! Crazy shit, I know. It is not that these scans take so long but they can.

IMO the only place where retina scans are everyday are for NEXUS cardholders entering Canada via air -- and even there, only those who are not Canadian citizens or residents because they have automated machines which do not require such hassle so it's absolutely marginal, a small fraction of a small fraction of passengers.

Comment: this is interesting information. good to know, thanks (+1)

Comment: Interesting that you mention that in the last paragraph. My impression was that they also do regular retina scans in Dubai at the airport (but for some weird religious reason only to women) and also if you apply for a visa for the US, at any US embassy.

Comment: Canadian citizens with NEXUS do use the retinal scan machines.  Everyone with NEXUS does when entering Canada by air.  Once you learn the tricks (which they teach you when they do the initial scan at the interview), it only takes about 15-30 seconds for the scan to work.

Comment: I always use the automated passport machines and never the NEXUS ones, I did so when I was a PR and still do now I am a citizen.

Comment: @woza I didn't know that. They came up with some truly scifi shit to expedite it though https://www.thenational.ae/uae/transport/dubai-airport-s-new-virtual-aquarium-tunnel-scans-your-face-as-you-walk-through-it-1.665406#5

Comment: I noticed retina scans in Dubai, but it seemed to be selective. I was not scanned.

Comment: This answer sounds scarily like it if were taken straight from the scripts of the next Blade Runner movie...

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Haha, yes, now that you mention it. Imagine how people 50 years would have felt if they would have read this.

Comment: The NEXUS machines are *iris* scanners, not retina scanners. In general, most biometric security devices based on the eye are iris scanners, the retina is not as reliable or easy to use biometric so is very rarely used, and in fact even descriptions of 'retina scan' biometric devices are often mistakenly describing iris scanners.

Answer (score 9):

I've come in internationally through Narita, Haneda, and Kansai International Airport, and have never had a retina scan or fingerprinted more than my index finger. They do take a picture of your face at each location, however.

As for flying domestically within the country, they don't do any of this, or even check id.

Comment: Good to have this confirmed. +1 for the information about domestic flights. Do you know if the picture is really with a small webcam, as jpatokal said in his answer? Is it a normal picture or an iris scan (which is different from a retina scan) ?

Comment: @Woza Iris and retina scans require you to look directly into a special camera very close-up (face almost pressed against camera) and special lighting. There is no way with present day technology (or even technology in the foreseeable future, think 5-10 years) that makes this possible at less than 10 centimeters distance between eye and camera. The pictures used for facial recognition and matching against biometric data in the passport are pretty low-res and can be from quite a distance. A full-HD cam can do this from 10-20 meters away. This is already standard tech for modern CCTV cameras.